# Cordova Dynamic Zoom & Meta Viewport Not Working

Tags: android, html, ios, css, cordova

I'm trying to dynamically enable / disable user zooming in my Cordova 3.4.0 app.

My initial viewport settings are:

```
<meta id="viewport-meta" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

When I enable zooming, I change to:

```
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi');
```

Then, to disable zooming and revert to original size, I execute:

```
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi');
```

Now, the problem is, after I manually pinch to zoom in when scaling is enabled, and when I try resetting the viewport to disable zooming, those initial-scale and maximum-scale do not take effect. Only the user-scalable takes effect, whereby I cannot pinch in / out anymore, but the page does not reset to the initial-scale / maximum-scale = 1, and remains at the zoomed level of say 2.

How do I force the page to zoom out again to the initial-scale of 1? Please advise. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap and cordova always renders app as a webpage so it is really not necessary to add such zooming code in my opinion.Zooming must automatically work unless it is disabled in config file.

But if it still doesnt work.Here's a plugin you can use

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

This plugin can be applied to your div's that will give you this feature.

You can also use hammer.js which is a javascript library that gives these facility

http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I intentionally disabled scaling in the index.html viewport meta tag because it's an app, and I wouldn't want users to zoom in like a web page. However, there are certain sections within the app like photo gallery that I would like to re-enable the functionality, so they can zoom into the photo, thus I would need to change the viewport settings. That's when the problem comes in - after setting it scalable and user pinch to zoom in, then when exiting photo gallery, resetting the viewport fails to auto zoom out again. Can you please advice? Thank you.

Comment: Are u accessing the phones galerry from your app or is the galerry part of your app

Comment: The "gallery" page is actually just a separate DIV layer within the same mobile app HTML page. When someone clicks on a thumbnail image at various sections of the app, my javascript outputs the image into that "gallery" DIV page with just the image and a black background, where the user can pinch to zoom in/out to view the full image. That "gallery" DIV enables the user-scalable, and when user exits that page, the user-scalable is set to no again.